# How should I improve cache friendliness of this code? (3D Complex array to 1D array of 2D matrices)

Tags: java, android, performance, caching, optimization

I am working on an Android app that deals with multichannel audio processing. The STFT function produces a complex frequency-time representation in the form of a 3D Complex array with dimensions nChannels by nFrames by nFreq.

However, in the next step, I need to perform blind source separation whose runtime benefits heavily from me moving the channels and frames of each frequency bin into a matrix. Currently, the code is rather cache-unfriendly when reading the entries of STFTin. Is there any way to make this more cache friendly?

```
    Complex[][] temp = new Complex[nFrames][nChannels];
    Complex[][] tempConj = new Complex[nFrames][nChannels];

    X = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix[nFreqs];
    Xcopy = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix[nFreqs];
    Xconj = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix[nFreqs];
    Y = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix[nFreqs];
    for (int f = 0; f < nFreqs; f++) {
        for (int t = 0; t < this.nFrames; t++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < this.nChannels; c++) {
                temp[t][c] = STFTin[c][t][f];
                tempConj[t][c] = STFTin[c][t][f].conjugate();
                //STFTin is nChannels by nFrames by nFreq
        }
        X[f] = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix<>(temp);
        Xconj[f] = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix<>(tempConj);
        Xcopy[f] = (Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex>) X[f].copy();
        Y[f] = (Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex>) X[f].copy();
    }
```

Comment: Would you be able to modify `STFT` to produce a `STFTin` with the reordered axes of `STFTin[f][t][c]`? If so, that itself would improve performance dramatically, and you could also extract each subarray in the previous for-loop, to avoid *that* time penalty. Otherwise, consider modifying a cache-friendly / cache-oblivious matrix transposition algorithm to place the transpose in your `temp`/`tempConj` arrays.

Comment: @DillonDavis unfortunately, to modifying the STFT function will only move the time penalty over to the STFT portion of the runtime, since the FFT function returns a complex arrays of size nFreq.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you'll probably want to adapt an existing cache-friendly matrix transposition algorithm to implement your logic (since that's the majority of what you're doing- a matrix transposition). Others have already fleshed out the implementation details regarding optimal block sizes, loop ordering, and how to account for edge cases (irregularly shaped matrices for example), so adapting existing code will result in both faster and less buggy code.

However, if you really need to roll your own solution, here's what I would try. First, reorder your loops so that the frequency and channel loops are inside the frames for-loop. You are accessing elements direct from a frequency subarray and storing them inside a channel subarray, so its important that we make the most of both of these while they are loaded into the cache; that's why we need to keep the frames loop on the outside.

Next, chunk your array accesses according to some proportion to your cache size. This way all of the frequency and channel subarrays we operate on can exist simultaneously in the cache- we won't obliterate the channel subarrays by reading too many values from the frequency arrays at once, or vice versa. There's ways to calculate this size, but honestly is more reliable and faster to just run it and time it- when things stop getting faster stop increasing the block size.

Rough code outline below:

```
Complex[][][] temp = new Complex[nFreqs][nFrames][nChannels];
Complex[][][] tempConj = new Complex[nFreqs][nFrames][nChannels];

int blockSizeF = 1 << 2;  // Increase these until you see no speedup
int blockSizeC = 1 << 3;

X = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix[nFreqs];
Xcopy = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix[nFreqs];
Xconj = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix[nFreqs];
Y = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix[nFreqs];
for (int t = 0; t < this.nFrames; t++) {
    for (int fBlock = 0; fBlock < nFreqs; fBlock += blockSizeF) {
        for (int cBlock = 0; cBlock < this.nChannels; cBlock += blockSizeC) {
            for (int f = fBlock; f < fBlock + blockSizeF; f++) {
                for (int c = cBlock; c < cBlock + blockSizeC; c++) {
                    temp[f][t][c] = STFTin[c][t][f];
                    tempConj[f][t][c] = STFTin[c][t][f].conjugate();
                    //STFTin is nChannels by nFrames by nFreq
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
for (int f = 0; f < nFreqs; f++) {
    X[f] = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix<>(temp[f]);
    Xconj[f] = new Array2DRowFieldMatrix<>(tempConj[f]);
    Xcopy[f] = (Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex>) X[f].copy();
    Y[f] = (Array2DRowFieldMatrix<Complex>) X[f].copy();
}
```

Normally `blockSizeF` and `blockSizeC` would be the same, but in this case for every one read into a frequency subarray of `STFTin`, you perform two writes into separate channel subarrays of `temp` and `tempConj`. That means you'll want a larger block size for channels than frequency- possibly a factor of `2`, maybe a factor of `sqrt(2)`- I'm not quite sure to be honest. I'd imagine it would be one of those two though, so I'd just experiment and find what works best. Either way, you'll probably want to round your block sizes off to the nearest power of two (or at least some multiple of a large power of two) to help align with the cache-lines or with page boundaries.

Note however, that `blockSizeF` and `blockSizeC` **absolutely must be** factors of `nFreqs` and `nChannels` respectively. There are ways around this stipulation, but its complex, slower, and error-prone. Its usually easier to just pad your matrix, and strip off the excess after the transformation.